# I would like to print the output that comes on the console to a text file. I tried the below but it didn't workout. Could anyone please look at this?

Tags: java, file-io, jdbc

The below is the code that I tried to print the output that comes on the console to a text file. The main idea of the code is fetch values from a csv file and print the output to a text file. Could someone let me know how this can be achieved.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.csvreader.CsvReader;

public class projectInfo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        Connection conn;

        int count = 0;

        String sampleIddisp = null;
        String sample_name = null;
        String compound_name = null;
        String registration_date = null;

            }
            products.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("\n Total number of records processed:" + count);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost all of your code is irrelevant. A single line of output `System.out.println("foo")` would be enough for a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). Please edit down your code accordingly

Comment: it doesnt give me any error. the output.txt file just remains blank.

Comment: StringBuffer buffer is initialized and never filled until it gets written. you need to append your text to the buffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never place any content in your `StringBuffer` `buffer`, so it is empty when you write it to file:

```
bw.write(buffer.toString());
```

`buffer` could potentially consume a large amount of memory here.

A better approach to writing the data to file would be to write the data as you read it from the database:

```
while (rs.next()) {
   sampleIddisp = rs.getString(1);
   ...

   bw.write(....);
}
```

Comment: The above solution works but when I package this to a Executable jar file it doesn't work. Any suggestions here ?

Comment: no, i don't receive any error, its like when I click on the Executable jar, its shows as processing and the txt files gets created but the file is blank.